# Dataweave to VM queue takes unexpectedly long time

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule4

We are pulling records from salesforce and at the max it could be 1 million. We are creating flatfile from the payload and pushing to the VM queue.
If the record size is small like 5K then pushing to VM queue takes just few seconds. But, if the record size exceeds like 15K publishing the message to vm queue is taking unexpected long time it's not getting completed.

I commented out the VM to check whether DW is taking more time but it's just take seconds to process the records.

I am pasting the config and code below. Why there is a bottle neck while pushing it to VM?
How I can resolve it?

VM config:

```
<vm:config name="VM_Config" doc:name="VM Config" doc:id="43bc7e5d-f387-4ad5-a1a8-bde183165f2c" >
        <vm:queues >
            <vm:queue queueName="lms" queueType="PERSISTENT"/>
        </vm:queues>
    </vm:config>
```

```
<flow name="create_flatFile" doc:id="63912901-4623-4b21-b659-d686b94e5fc6" >
        <set-variable value="#[0]" doc:name="Counter" doc:id="a0765cec-ad3b-4262-9681-f7c31a2391d7" variableName="batchCounter" />
        <ee:transform doc:name="Json to VPS File" doc:id="2e091d10-c526-43f0-af55-e42f10be9316">
            <ee:message>
                <ee:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
import * from dw::core::Strings
output application/flatfile schemaPath = "schemas/VPS.ffd", structureIdent="MultiSegment", missingValues="spaces", deferred=true, bufferSize=16384


fun getFieldData(item) =  {
    "Statement_Message_ID__c": "014205",
    "Option_Set__c": "019303",
    ("ASC__c": "011206") if(!isBlank(item.ASC__c)),
    ("CDF23__c": "008902") if(!isBlank(item.CDF23__c ))
}
---
{
  vps: {
    vps: [
      {
        ":USRDSB:-SOURCE": {
          ":USRDSB:-SOURCE": "SOURCE",
          ":USRDSB:-SOURCE-ID ": "MULESOFT"
        },
        ":USRDSB:-HEADER": {
          ":USRDSB:-HEADER": "HEADER",
          ":USRDSB:-TRANSMISSION-ID": "SPLNSCRB"
        },  
        ":USRDSB:-DETAIL-RECORD": vars.eligibleRecords flatMap (item)->
         entriesOf(getFieldData(item)) map {
                ":USRDSB:-FIELD-IND": $.value,
                ":USRDSB:-CARD-NBR": rightPad(leftPad(item.TSYS_ID__c as Number ,11,0),19,' '),
                ":USRDSB:-FIELD-DATA": if($.value ~="014205") item.Statement_Message_ID__c 
                                       else if($.value ~="019303") item.Option_Set__c
                                       else if($.value ~="008902")leftPad(item.CDF23__c,2,0)
                                       else item.ASC__c
            }
      },
    ]
  }
}]]></ee:set-payload>
            </ee:message>
        </ee:transform>
        <vm:publish doc:name="Publish" doc:id="cf145508-87c4-4b43-a786-7d153a426659" queueName="lms" timeout="30" config-ref="VM_Config" transactionalAction="NOT_SUPPORTED">
                    </vm:publish>
        <logger level="INFO" message="Aggregation complete" />
    </flow>
```

Comment: Is this a cluster? Standalone? CloudHub?

Comment: Not getting complete means a timeout? Share the errors in the logs.

Comment: @aled I am testing this in my local machine code will be deployed in CH 2.0. Publishing message from DW to VM queue is taking long time and the process was never completed even after waiting for 10min. Payload size is around 2MB

Comment: Versions of Mule, connectors, Studio?

Comment: Try to reproduce the issue removing the DataWeave script, just read a file of the same size.

Comment: @aled Mule runtime 4.4.0, VM connector 2.0.0,

Comment: @aled can we write the file to /tmp in CH and push it to SFTP and delete the file from /tmp?

Comment: @aled I did commented out the DW. Read the file which is around 120MB pushed it to queue and queue to SFTP. It just took less than 10 seconds. Basically, bottleneck when dataweave trying to push to VM

Comment: @codebeget did you try with DW deferrer? https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/latest/dataweave-streaming

Comment: @AnuragSharma I did yes. I have posted my DW above!

Comment: It is still not clear which step is taking time. You need to do more research and share the exact time taken in 1. Fetching the 1M records, 2. Execution of the dataweave script 3. Execution of `vm:publish` operation

Comment: @HarshankBansal I mentioned that publishing to VM takes more time if the size of the records are increased.

Comment: Is this correct? 1. big file, DW to file, not slow.  2. big file, file to VM, not slow, 3. small file, DW to VM, not slow. 4. big file, DW to VM, slow

Comment: @RyanHoegg You are right. DW to VM or DW to SFTP is the process where it's choked.

Comment: OK please do an experiment without VM.  Salesforce to local file, then read local file and send to SFTP and report back performance